# Excel: Formulaic single-cell solution for 1-dimensional subtotal based on arrays

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Required to aggregate values from a Table based on specified column values into corresponding dynamic array of subtotals without VBA or "hard-coded" individual references.

**Preconditions:**

1. Formula-based solution (i.e., no VBA)
2. The solution to produce *Required output *from the *Original data* with *Parameter* is **contained in a single cell.**

**Original data:**

```
  Label 1   Label 2   Label 3 
|  ID_01  |    A    |     1   |
|  ID_02  |    D    |     1   |
|  ID_03  |    C    |     2   |
|  ID_04  |    B    |     3   |
|  ID_05  |    C    |     5   |
|  ID_06  |    A    |     8   |
|  ID_07  |    E    |    12   |
|  ID_08  |    C    |    21   |
```

**Parameter:**

`<Label 2> = {A,B,C}`

**Required output:**

```
  Label 2   Label 3  
|    A    |     9   |
|    B    |     3   |
|    C    |    28   |
```

Note: {9,3,28} is enough here, a table is not necessary

**EDIT**: My actual use-case utilizes filters for the parameters, which currently ends up in #VALUE! -errors (see. *Filter values and formula output* -link):

```
=LET(D,FILTER(Original_data[Label 1],ISNUMBER(SEARCH(Filter_1,Original_data[Label 3]))*(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(Filter_2,Original_data[Label 5])))),
     B,UNIQUE(FILTER(Original_data[Label 2],ISNUMBER(MATCH(Original_data[Label 1],D,0)))),
     C,FILTER(Original_data[Label 4],ISNUMBER(MATCH(Original_data[Label 1],D,0))),
     A,FILTER(Original_data[Label 2],ISNUMBER(MATCH(Original_data[Label 1],D,0))),
     E,SUMIF(A,B,C),
     IFNA(HSTACK(A,B,C,D,E),""))
```

[Used dummy data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pFQXO.png)

[Filter values and formula output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/buPXD.png)

**EDIT 2**: MAP() -solution works

```
=LET(D,FILTER(Original_data[Label 1],ISNUMBER(SEARCH(Filter_1,Original_data[Label 3]))*(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(Filter_2,Original_data[Label 5])))),
     B,UNIQUE(FILTER(Original_data[Label 2],ISNUMBER(MATCH(Original_data[Label 1],D,0)))),
     C,FILTER(Original_data[Label 4],ISNUMBER(MATCH(Original_data[Label 1],D,0))),
     A,FILTER(Original_data[Label 2],ISNUMBER(MATCH(Original_data[Label 1],D,0))),
     E,MAP(B,LAMBDA(Y,SUM((A=Y)*C))),
     IFNA(HSTACK(A,B,C,D,E),""))
```

[Filter values and formula output (Working as expected)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xkfGn.png)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something along these lines perhaps:

[image]

Formula in `E2`:

```
=LET(x,TOCOL({"A","B","C"}),HSTACK(x,SUMIF(B2:B9,x,C2:C9)))
```

Or, if you just need the seperate sums as per the body of your question:

```
=SUMIF(B2:B9,TOCOL({"A","B","C"}),C2:C9)
```

[image]

---

For OP's array objects:

```
=LET(x,TOCOL({"A","B","C"}),HSTACK(x,MAP(x,LAMBDA(y,SUM((B2:B9=y)*C2:C9)))))
```

Comment: Ah, should have known it was this simple. This works with dummy data, but I seem to be getting #VALUE! -errors with the actual data. Any ideas why?

Comment: @mintti, depends. Do you want to show us some more actual case-related data?

Comment: I can't share the example file I created here, but I did some triage and it seems like the <range> and <sum range> parameters of SUMIF() cannot be FILTER() outputs. If they are, the overall output is a #VALUE! -error.

Comment: Correct, `SUMIF()` needs an actual range reference to work. I'll edit the answer to account for your array object. @mintti

Comment: `MMULT` is the alternative of SUMIF(s) which does allow arrays: `=LET(x,{"A";"B";"C"},HSTACK(x,MMULT(--(TOROW(Original_data[Label2])=x),Original_data[Label3])))`

Comment: How would I best approach adding a second dimension to the output? For instance if there was a <Label 4> with values {X,Y,Y,Z,X,Y,X,Z}, how could I get the summed <Label 3> values correspondingly represented with <Label 2> {A,B,C} on the y-axis and <Label 4> {X,Y,Z} on the x-axis?

Comment: @mintti, typically through an boolean structure. Something along these lines perhaps: `=LET(x,TOCOL({"A","B","C"}),y,TOCOL({"X","Y","Z"}),HSTACK(x,y,MAP(x,y,LAMBDA(a,b,SUM((B2:B9=b)*(D2:D9=b)*C2:C9)))))`

Comment: I posted a new question for clarity: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76911661/excel-formulaic-single-cell-solution-for-2-dimensional-subtotals-based-on-array

Answer (score 0):

Alternative approach using <kbd>WRAPCOLS( )</kbd>, <kbd>SUMIF( )</kbd>

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>F4</kbd>

```
=LET(α,F2#,WRAPCOLS(HSTACK(α,SUMIF(B2:B9,α,C2:C9)),COLUMNS(α)))
```

---