# Excel: Formulaic single-cell solution for 2-dimensional subtotals based on arrays

Tags: excel, excel-formula

*(Extension of the [1-dimensional case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76904105/excel-formulaic-single-cell-solution-for-1-dimensional-subtotal-based-on-arrays) asked prior)*

Required to aggregate values from a Table based on specified column values into corresponding dynamic array of 2-dimensional subtotals without VBA or "hard-coded" individual references.

**Preconditions:**

1. Formula-based solution (i.e., no VBA)
2. The solution to produce *Required output *from the *Table* with *Parameters* is **contained in a single cell.**

**Table:**

| Label 1 | Label 2 | Label 3 | Label 4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ID_01 | A | 1 | X |
| ID_02 | D | 1 | X |
| ID_03 | C | 2 | Z |
| ID_04 | B | 3 | Y |
| ID_05 | C | 5 | Y |
| ID_06 | A | 8 | Y |
| ID_07 | E | 12 | X |
| ID_08 | C | 21 | Z |

**Parameters** (*array outputs from FILTER() -formulas*)**:**

`<Label 2> = {"A","B","C"}`

`<Label 4> = {"X","Y","Z"}`

**Required output:**

|  | X | Y | Z |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | 8 | 0 |
| B | 0 | 3 | 0 |
| C | 0 | 5 | 23 |

**Note:** *{{1,8,0},{0,3,0},{0,5,23}}* is enough here, a new table is not necessary

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using the following formula using <kbd>MAKEARRAY( )</kbd>

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>F4</kbd>

```
=LET(
     a,TOCOL(G1#),
     b,TOROW(G2#),
     c,MAKEARRAY(ROWS(a),COLUMNS(b),LAMBDA(x,y,SUM((B2:B9=INDEX(a,x))*(D2:D9=INDEX(b,y))*C2:C9))),
     VSTACK(HSTACK("",b),
     HSTACK(a,c)))
```

---

Or, if you need only the values, using <kbd>MMULT( )</kbd>, <kbd>TOROW( )</kbd>, <kbd>TOCOL( )</kbd> & <kbd>WRAPCOLS( )</kbd>

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>F4</kbd>

```
=LET(
     a,G1#,
     b,G2#,
     c,TOCOL(a&"|"&TOCOL(b)),
     d,TOROW(B2:B9&"|"&D2:D9),
     WRAPCOLS(MMULT(N(c=d),C2:C9),3))
```

---

Clearly, if you don't need a new table, then <kbd>MAKEARRAY( )</kbd> would be right to use.

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>G5</kbd>

```
=LET(
     a,F5#,
     b,G4#,
     MAKEARRAY(ROWS(a),COLUMNS(b),LAMBDA(r,c,
     SUM((INDEX(a,r)=B2:B9)*(INDEX(b,c)=D2:D9)*C2:C9))))
```

---

Comment: The third formula with the MAKEARRAY() works well. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively:

[image]

Formula in `F2`:

```
=LET(x,{"A","B","C"},y,{"X","Y","Z"},z,TOCOL(y),REDUCE(HSTACK("",y),x,LAMBDA(a,b,VSTACK(a,HSTACK(b,MAP(y,LAMBDA(q,SUM((B2:B9=b)*(D2:D9=q)*C2:C9))))))))
```

---

Or, if you just need the values:

```
=LET(x,{"A","B","C"},y,{"X","Y","Z"},DROP(REDUCE(0,x,LAMBDA(a,b,VSTACK(a,MAP(y,LAMBDA(q,SUM((B2:B9=b)*(D2:D9=q)*C2:C9)))))),1))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

He is another approach-

```
=LET(
x,SORT(UNIQUE(B2:B9)),
y,TRANSPOSE(SORT(UNIQUE(D2:D9))),
VSTACK(HSTACK("",y),HSTACK(x,SUMIFS(C2:C9,B2:B9,x,D2:D9,y)))
)
```

[image]

Comment: Can <x> and <y> be arrays here, not ranges?

Comment: @mintti Yes, but sum range must be sheet range.